# AngularJS Directive, ng-repeat and a Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, flexslider

I have a section at my html where I load testimonials and I'm using flexslider on it.

The markup looks like this:

```
<section class="testimonials">
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 column">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h2>
                    <span>- Author Name</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h2>
                    <span>- Author Name</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h2>
                    <span>- Author Name</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h2>
                    <span>- Author Name</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h2>
                    <span>- Author Name</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="author-thumbs">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <span class="container">
                            <img src="assets/img/testimonial-author-pic.jpg" alt="">
                        </span> 
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <span class="container">
                            <img src="assets/img/testimonial-author-pic.jpg" alt="">
                        </span> 
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <span class="container">
                            <img src="assets/img/testimonial-author-pic.jpg" alt="">
                        </span> 
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <span class="container">
                            <img src="assets/img/testimonial-author-pic.jpg" alt="">
                        </span> 
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At first I got in trouble because since Angular was loading the partial file after the document was ready, my sliders stopped working. So I moved the flexslider initialization to a directive. Like this:

```
app.directive('testimonials', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find('.author-thumbs').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: "thumbnails",
            controlNav: false, 
            directionNav: false,
            itemWidth: 80,
            minItems: 4,
            maxItems: 4,
            asNavFor: ".testimonials .flexslider",
        });
        element.find('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: "thumbnails",
            controlNav: false, 
            directionNav: false,
            smoothHeight: true,
            sync: ".testimonials .author-thumbs"
        });
    }
};
});
```

This way I got it to work adding testimonials at the section html.

Okay, but now I want to take this static content and move it to my controller and make a ng-repeat. So I did this:

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.testimonials = [
        {"quote":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod", "author":"Author Name", "img":"assets/img/testimonial-author-pic.jpg"},
        {"quote":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.", "author":"Author Name", "img":"assets/img/testimonial-author-pic.jpg"},
        {"quote":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod", "author":"Author Name", "img":"assets/img/testimonial-author-pic.jpg"},
        {"quote":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod", "author":"Author Name", "img":"assets/img/testimonial-author-pic.jpg"},
    ]
});
```

Created a new file for the testimonials section markup and changed it's directive to be of type E:

```
app.directive('testimonials', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'partials/elements/testimonials.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.find('.author-thumbs').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: "thumbnails",
                controlNav: false, 
                directionNav: false,
                itemWidth: 80,
                minItems: 4,
                maxItems: 4,
                asNavFor: ".testimonials .flexslider",
            });
            element.find('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: "thumbnails",
                controlNav: false, 
                directionNav: false,
                smoothHeight: true,
                sync: ".testimonials .author-thumbs"
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And now... Well, now the testimonials show up but the flexslider is not being initialized. Anyone know what I did wrong? I'm looking for and answer that could explain WHY what I did is wrong, since I'm trying to learn it.

I'm running angularjs 1.3.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this working wrapping the flexslider initialization inside $timeout, like this:

```
app.directive('testimonials', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'partials/elements/testimonials.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function(){
                element.find('.author-thumbs').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    controlNav: "thumbnails",
                    controlNav: false, 
                    directionNav: false,
                    itemWidth: 80,
                    minItems: 4,
                    maxItems: 4,
                    asNavFor: ".testimonials .flexslider",
                });
                element.find('.flexslider').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    controlNav: "thumbnails",
                    controlNav: false, 
                    directionNav: false,
                    smoothHeight: true,
                    sync: ".testimonials .author-thumbs"
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

What happens is, since my testimonials variable is hardcoded I need $timeout to run the javascript after everything is done loading.

When I change it to load the testimonials from the server, $watch would probably be a better solution like Dennis Smolek suggested because an actual change to testimonials would happen, triggering flexlider init. I'm not 100% sure since I haven't tested it yet, but I strongly believe that this is going to work. I'll update this answer when I make the changes and test it

Answer (score 0):

So you'll find when you update your content in the ng-repeat your slides will probably not work right as they wont be attached to the flexslider call but I haven't tried flexslider/Angular.

First I don't think you need the directive if your plan is simply to fire on loading the content. Your controller should be able to catch it.

The reason WHY it's not working is that when the link function  runs in the digest loop those elements dont exist so you are calling flexslider on nothing, then the next part of the loop comes around and injects your repeat with content but you've already run your call.

I would do a $watch and setup function:

```
function setupFlexslider() {
    //your flexslider code
} 
$scope.$watch('testimonials', function(newData,oldData) {
   if(newData){
       setupFlexslider();
   }
}
```

So this will fire when you fill that value (elements should exist) and if you change them it will refire. Only thing I dont know right now is what happens when you fire flexslider twice...

Comment: Yea.. I imagined that my call was happening before the ng-repeat could finish loading everything.

I've put my javascript and code inside a directive because I've done quite a bit of research and it looks like it is a best practice to leave this kind of stuff out of the controller. I'm not sure.

I got it to work with $timeout, I'm going to try your solution tonight with this $watch service that I'm not still familiar with and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I just tested it out. At my current state it will not work.
As of my research on $watch, it will keep looking for changes on the testimonials and then it will run the setupFlexslider(). Since my testimonials variable is still hardcoded, no change is being made, so the watch is not running. It will probably work as I load testimonials data from the server in the future. However, at least for now, $timeout is the way to go. BTW, I confirmed, you should leave all DOM manipulation outside of the controller, that's why the directive deals with it.

Comment: I understand the logic of moving DOM out of the controller but I think too often in Angular people create useless directives. What if you wanted to then use flexslider for images,videos, or something else? With the directive approach you end up with 3 directives for the same basic call.  I'm going to spin up a fiddle and play with this..

Comment: The same thing would happen without angular. In your normal js file you would have 3 different calls with 3 different arguments for example.

Comment: So I played with this for a while and got this to work: http://jsfiddle.net/gmyjLfLz/1/
It uses a directive for the slide object and when the last element calls its scope it fires the render call (kept out of the controller and directive just to play around with it)
I don't know if this is any better/worse than wrapping it in the $timeout call with the values being hardcoded. If you're going to pull those values from a server though I'd still use a $watch. Good question, got me thinking...